# Reading strings into Matlab from excel?

Tags: string, excel, matlab, file-io

I would like to read strings into Matlab from an excel file

```
ID = xlsread('data.xlsx',1, 'D2:D4')
```

the cells in range D2:D4  have strings in them. When I try to import the strings into Matlab all I get is an empty list? what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're in Matlab 2010 you can also do something like this to avoid having extra values in your workspace.

```
[~, ~, raw] = xlsread('data.xlsx',1, 'D2:D4')
```

Comment: The 3-argument output is available in older versions as well; I'm not sure how far back it goes.

In my experience, the raw output is superior to using the [num,txt] outputs because MATLAB "helpfully" discards non-numeric header rows and/or columns around the edges of the num output.

Comment: By the "in matlab 2010" I meant using `~` as a way of specifying an output but not actually naming any variables ... in the other example `[num, txt, raw] = xlsread('data.xlsx',1, 'D2:D4')` you will have an extra `num` and `txt` variable in your workspace.

Answer (score 6):

I need to use this
[num, txt, raw] = xlsread('data.xlsx',1, 'D2:D4')

the txt will import stings into Matlab.