# xlsread function in matlab systematically loads the whole file and not the specified cells

Tags: matlab

I used the command

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(excelPath,1,'C2:C3')
```

as it was done here ([Reading strings into Matlab from excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104473/reading-strings-into-matlab-from-excel)) but matlab systematically loaded the whole excel file. I don't need all the table and only want the specific cells C2 and C3. How can I do this ? (A more brutal solution would be to load the whole file and then look for the right place in *num*, *txt* or *raw* but I look for the other solution)

Thanks !

Comment: What's your OS and MATLAB version?

Comment: It's a Linux and Matlab 7.9.0 (R2009b)

Comment: That explains it then. Check the doc for `xlsread`: "basic mode, the default on systems without Excel for Windows" and "Does not support an xlRange input when reading XLS files. In this case, use '' in place of xlRange."

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you just tried

```
num = xlsread(excelPath,1,'C2:C3')
```

Does this load only the specified cells?

**EDIT**

if you are using `xlsread` on a non-Windows O/S, then it uses the basic mode which "does not support an xlRange input when reading XLS files. In this case, use '' in place of xlRange."  See the [documentation](http://mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) for the `xlsread` function for more info.

Comment: Can you update your answer as you posted the solution in a comment?